# I accidentally installed 64 and 32-bit python 2.7.8 and now it acts strangely

Tags: python, python-2.7

Oops.

I uninstalled both pythons afterwards and re-downloaded the 32-bit.

Now I'm trying to open a `test.txt` file after starting python in PowerShell and it gives me this

```
>>> open('C:/test/test.txt')
<open file 'C:/test/test.txt', mode 'r' at 0x021CB7B0> 

>>> open('C:/test/test.txt')
<open file 'C:/test/test.txt', mode 'r' at 0x021CB758>

>>> open('C:/test/test.txt')
<open file 'C:/test/test.txt', mode 'r' at 0x021CB7B0>

>>> open('C:/test/test.txt')
<open file 'C:/test/test.txt', mode 'r' at 0x021CB758>
```

and it continues alternating without opening the text file at all.

Also `python -v` on windows powershell gives me:

[image]

How can I fix my python?

Answer (score 3):

This is ordinary behavior with Python objects (including `file` objects returned by `open`). It has to do with garbage collection, and nothing to do with the installation issues you were having.

When you call `open`, it creates a new `file` object. The text `<open file 'C:/test/test.txt', mode 'r' at 0x021CB7B0>` is the file object's `repr`. Later, when object will be garbage collected. Later still, when you create another new object, the memory from the first object may be reused. This is why you can see the same memory address more than once.

The reason that you see two addresses alternating is a bit more subtle. When you run the Python interpreter in interactive mode, it prints the `repr` of the value of any expression you type at the prompt (skipping `None` only). It also stores the most recently printed value in the variable `_` (a single underscore). This means that each time you open that file, the returned `file` object is bound to `_` for a short time. When you create the next `file` object, it replaces the first one in `_` and the old file gets garbage collected (because it's not referred to by any other part of the code).

When you create the third file, it reuses the memory the first file used, since it's now free. It rebinds `_` again, so the second file object is garbage collected. Now, when you create the fourth file, it reuses the memory from the second one. If you were to continue to create and destroy file objects (without doing anything else in between), the alternating memory addresses would continue indefinitely.

If you wrote your code a bit differently, you'd get different results. For instance, if you appended each newly opened `file` object to a list after creating it, they'd all end up with different memory addresses (since they'd all exist in memory at the same time).

```
file_objects = []
for i in range(5):
    file_objects.append(open('C:/test/test.txt'))
print file_objects
```

However, while that's illustrative of what's going on, it sounds like what you really want is to open and read the contents of the file. To do that, you need to call the `read` method on the file object you get from `open`. A best practice is to use call `open` as part of a `with` statement, as this ensures that the file gets closed again after you're done with it:

```
with open('C:/test/test.txt') as f:  # open the file, bind the file object to name f
    text = f.read()                  # read the file contents into text
                                     # the file is closed when the indented block ends
print text                           # print the contents read from the file
```

Comment: OK, thanks, that cleared that up, I guess I just misunderstood what it was supposed to be doing. But what about the image in my post, is that normal or is there something wrong with my python installation?

Comment: @pythonq: That seems normal to me. `python -v` verbosely reports all the imports that are needed to get the interactive interpreter running. If you import other modules later, you'll get a verbose message about them too.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's the indented result. [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) returns a [`file-object`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#bltin-file-objects)

if you want to read the content then you have use

`open(r'C:\test\test.txt').read()`

But it's better to use something like this,

```
with open(r'C:\test\test.txt') as f:
    print f.read();
```